# How can I make matplotlib plot not round my values down automatically and how can I make my numbers more readable?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

0I have this code were I am making a bar chart, the problem is that my BNP (GDP) values are pretty large, we are talking millions, billions and trillions. When I plot these values they get rounded down to 1, 2, 3, 4 etc. Is there a way I can get the actual values, I feel like it would give much more sence compared to those small numbers?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.barh(landStolpediagram, BNPStolpediagram)
plt.xlabel("BNP")
plt.ylabel("Land")
plt.title("Dine valgte land og deres BNP verdi")
plt.show()
```

I wanted to use this function to round the numbers

```
def konverter(tall):
    magnitude = 0
    while abs(tall) >= 1000:
        magnitude += 1
        tall /= 1000.0
    return '%.3f%s' % (tall, ['', 'K', 'Mn', 'Bn', 'Tn'][magnitude])
```

The problem with this is that the lowest GDP value want have a bar. Any solutions? Also, if I use the function the values wont be sorted from lowest to biggest, how can I fix that?

Extra:
When I run the numbers through the funciton "konverter" it will plot a graph like this

[image]

This is what I want, I just want the values to be sorted from lower to higher and that the lowest country will have a bar.

Answer (score 0):

you should be using log scale on the X axis.

you can also use `plt.xticks` to modify the label of your x axis to be whatever you want it to be.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

landStolpediagram = ["ex1","ex2"]
BNPStolpediagram = [1,2e10]
plt.barh(landStolpediagram, BNPStolpediagram)
plt.xlabel("BNP")
plt.ylabel("Land")
plt.title("Dine valgte land og deres BNP verdi")
plt.xscale('log')  # This line sets x axis to log scale
def konverter(tall):
    magnitude = 0
    if tall < 10:
        return str(tall)
    while abs(tall) >= 1000:
        magnitude += 1
        tall /= 1000.0
    return '%d%s' % (tall, ['', 'K', 'Mn', 'Bn', 'Tn'][magnitude])
plt.xticks(plt.xticks()[0],[konverter(x) for x in plt.xticks()[0]])
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: I have though of this solution, but is there a way I can use the function I made to show the actual values while also making it easier to read?

Comment: @AndreasKarlsen recheck the answer now.